# Easier way to induce an orientation to the border of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm working in the following exercise:

> Let $M=\{(x, y, z): x²+y²=1 \,\text{and}\, 0\leq z \leq 1\}$. Let $\alpha:(0,1)²\rightarrow \mathbb R³$ be given by $\alpha(u, v)=(\cos u, \sin u, v)$. Consider the orientation of $M$ such that $\alpha$ belongs to it. Describe the normal unitary vector corresponding to this orientation. Describe the tangent vector of $\partial M$ corresponding to the orientation induced by this orientation of $M$.

My attempt:

Consider $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4$ given by:

$\alpha_1: (0, 1)\times [0, 1)$, $\alpha_2: (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2})\times [0, 1)$ given by $\alpha_i(u, v)=(\cos u, \sin u, v)$

$\alpha_3: (-1, 0)\times [0, 1)$, $\alpha_4: (-\frac{3}{2}, -\frac{1}{2})\times [0, 1)$ given by the formula $\alpha_i(u, v)=(\cos -u, \sin -u, 1-v)$.

It's easy, but long and boring to verify that the determinants of the differential of all the following functions are all positive where they are defined:

$$\alpha\circ\alpha_1^{-1}, \alpha\circ\alpha_2^{-1},\alpha\circ\alpha_3^{-1},\alpha\circ\alpha_4^{-1},\alpha_1\circ\alpha_2^{-1},\alpha_1\circ\alpha_3^{-1}, \alpha_1\circ\alpha_4^{-1}, \alpha_2\circ\alpha_3^{-1}, \alpha_2\circ\alpha_4^{-1}, \alpha_3\circ\alpha_4^{-1}$$

Now all we have to do is to calculate the cross products, normalize them, to restrict these functions to the border adjusting the sign and finally, to calculate the tangent vectors and normalize them.

As you can see, this is a very long solution if you need to write all the details. Therefore, I'm not satisfied with my solution. Is there a way to make a shorter solution?